# php perform isset in if statement without grouped statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, isset, array-key

I have this if statement

```
if ($something !== $array[$key]) {
    // do something
}
```

But I can't be 100% sure that `$array[$key]` exists.
So I'd like to do something like this:

```
if ($something !== $array[$key] ?? null) {
    // do something
}
```

The if statement should run when the array key does not exist or or different from the variable.
Of course, I could do something like this:

```
if ($something !== (isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : null)) {
    // do something
}
```

But I want to avoid this since it makes the code less readable. Are there any other options except this one:

```
$compare = $array[$key] ?? null;
if ($something !== $compare) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: so why exactly `$something !== $array[$key] ?? null` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @AlexBlex, probably because of "Notice: Undefined offset:" if $array[$key] isn't set.

Comment: The `$something !== $array[$key] ?? null` doesn't work for me because I get a notice: `Undefined index:`.

Comment: ah, fair enough. A pair of parenthesis should fix it: `$something !== ($array[$key] ?? null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code might help:

```
if (!array_key_exists($key, $array) || $array[$key] !== $something) {
   // Do it
}
```